# What is a real life example of a ring buffer/circular queue?

Tags: data-structures, circular-buffer

These are some examples I could think off but I don't think they are perfect:-

1. [Conga Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conga_line)(Dance):- Not perfect because people enter at the end of the circular queue but exit randomly. (People just leave randomly not in a serial fashion)
2. Airport Baggage Carousel:- Same reason as above. The baggages are picked by their owners at random.
3. Ferris Wheel:- Entry is in sequence, exit is in sequence as well. Once  the ride is done, the position where exit starts from can be random  (except the high roller in Las Vegas which lets everyone do exactly 1 rotation and is the one perfect example that I could find)

Comment: You have to imagine back to when tape storage was a thing, and the US FCC mandated a 7 second delay on broadcasts lest someone say a profanity on the radio. These were often implemented as a tape recorder / player with a 7 second loop of tape between heads. 8-track tape players used a long loop tape but for convenience of not rewinding, not queuing.

Comment: And what do you think is a perfect circular queue?